# How can a working student reference a completed co-authored manuscript in their online portfolio?

Tags: career-path, cv, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

**TLDR:** Please advise how a tech professional/working student may go about referencing co-authorship on manuscripts that were submitted to academic publications in a resume or online portfolio?

*Background:* I'm a final year BSc student at one of the major NYC schools working in a data analyst/assistant role under a research scientist at the med school. My degree and career path is more industry-oriented than academic as an aspiring data scientist.

Although my supervisor is a professor at the med school, my work is not funded by the school—I was hired on the basis of my professional experience with statistical analysis tools. I'm paid through the business of the head research scientist and main author on the studies, who independently funds the projects and is based out of another US university. I am included as a co-author on two submitted manuscripts for statistical data analysis performed for the projects.

Is there an appropriate way to demo my work in an online portfolio whether or not it is accepted for publication?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely mention these manuscripts in your resume or online portfolio. To do that, you give the manuscript title and full author list as it appears in the submission, and mention the word **submitted** either in a section heading or with the reference itself. If you want to explain more about your contribution to these manuscripts, you can write a brief paragraph in which you describe the relevant points.

For a resume that is not publicly accessible, you could even add specific information from the manuscript, such as abstract, figures that show your contribution, or even the full manuscript as might be helpful for your resume. However, for that you need approval of the other authors. Best would be to inform the lead author and the corresponding author which information you want to use where and ask them for approval. They can coordinate with any other co-authors if necessary. Also, you clearly need to indicate that what you show is from a submitted, not yet accepted / published, work.

For a publicly accessible online portfolio, you should usually not disclose information beyond what is stated in the first paragraph of this answer. If all authors agree, it would be possible to publish the manuscript as a pre-print, and you could then link to that from your portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [silvado's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/168532/20058), let me make a few remarks:

1. *Submitted* is the appropriate status for a paper that has been submitted to a journal or conference and is possibly under review. Don't specify the journal which you have submitted to, because you don't know in advance whether it will be accepted there or not.
2. Once the paper is accepted, you can modify the status as *in press*, and in this case you can specify the journal. Moreover, nowadays, many journals put online the final revision of the manuscript within 24 h of the acceptance, and assign already the DOI: in such a case, you can also add the link to your online portfolio.